# How do I use my R4i SDHC on my Nintendo DSi XL?

Tags: nintendo-ds

I have a R4i SDHC and it stopped working with my Nintendo DSi XL (1.4.1e).

What firmware should I try on my flashcard?

Comment: For what purpose are you using that card other than loading illegally acquired software?

Comment: @Bora There's a decent amount of homebrew for the DS. Some of it's actually good. Some of the firmwares for the various cards have the ability to play music formats which the DS doesn't support. I'd assume there are some that can play video too. (transcoded and low quality only probably)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to be easy, but I'll try:

First: Your flashcard is one of the countless R4 clones/fakes out there, which makes it difficult to tell which firmware will work on it. Or, to put it less optimistic, won't [brick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_%28electronics%29) your flashcard.

To make matters worse, there are at least 7 different flashcards called "R4i SDHC" on gbatemps [Ultimate Flashcard Download Index](http://wiki.gbatemp.net/wiki/Ultimate_Flashcart_Download_Index), and there is no way to tell which firmware will work.

Then again, maybe your flashcard simply broke. This answer probably isn't very helpful. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you, the link to gbatemps is really useful. there I have found a [similar one](http://www.linfoxdomain.com/nintendo/ds/). I will go on testing a couple of firmware and let you know which one works. Is there any test I can do, to see if the flashcard is bricked?

Answer (score -2):

It seems that your firmware has been upgraded, and you need to download the latest kernel from the official website and that should work.